# Pandas the fastest way read_csv array column as an array rather than string

Tags: python, arrays, pandas

I have a test.csv file like

```
"item_id","array"
"1","[1,2,3]"
"2","[3,5]"
"2","[4,5,6,7]"
```

When I use read this csv using pandas like below, the array column is a string type.

```
data = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
c = data["array"][0]    # c is a string '[1,2,3]'
```

I would like c=[1,2,3], which is a list or a numpy array.

Is there any way to do so quickly? Since the data can be very large. The for-loop or data["array"].apply(ast.literal_eval) is slow in my real data.

Comment: Try `data = pd.read_csv("test.csv", converters={"array": json.loads})` or in your solution `data['array'] = data.array.apply(json.loads)`

Comment: @jezrael thanks for your solution. Yes, json.loads is faster than ast.literal_eval. But is there a way to directly convert as numpy array instead of list?

Comment: can you try `converters={"array": lambda x: np.array(json.loads(x))})` ?